# NTP rollover-safe design with ESP8266 (Curiosity)

Tags: esp8266, time

The Arduino NTP implementation is rather naive in some respects. It basically just grabs the time in seconds from the raw packet, and then converts it to Unix time via subtraction. How would it be possible to create an implementation that is safe from at least this next NTP rollover (due in 2036)? I'd rather not design something that might suddenly fail in strange ways in a decade or two when I have forgotten why it might do so (but it's not horribly important if it's not easily fixed).

If it can make it to 2100, I'd have larger problems (the RTC would crap itself), so just this rollover is fine.

The existing implementation (https://github.com/arduino-libraries/NTPClient/blob/master/NTPClient.cpp):

```cpp
unsigned long highWord = word(this->_packetBuffer[40], this->_packetBuffer[41]);
unsigned long lowWord = word(this->_packetBuffer[42], this->_packetBuffer[43]);
// combine the four bytes (two words) into a long integer
// this is NTP time (seconds since Jan 1 1900):
unsigned long secsSince1900 = highWord << 16 | lowWord;

this->_currentEpoc = secsSince1900 - SEVENZYYEARS;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This implementation is perfectly fine. The calculations are done with
unsigned numbers, so they are naturally rollover safe. The day NTP time
rolls over, `secsSince1900` will become a very small number, and
subtracting `SEVENZYYEARS` from it will cause an extra roll over. Owing
to the rules of modular arithmetics, these two rollovers compensate and
you are guaranteed to get the correct result modulo
2<sup>32</sup> s.

In the end, you get a Unix time as an unsigned 32-bit integer. Unix time
is traditionally signed, which makes the 32-bit representation roll over
in January 2038. The authors of this library have instead chosen to
represent it as an *unsigned* number, which means it will roll over in
February 2106.

Comment: Huh. That's actually rather cool. I knew of a similar method for millis(), but didn't know this worked for NTP as well. Thanks!

Comment: @RDragonrydr: carry propagates from low to high in addition/subtraction.  The low bits of the result do *not* depend on any higher bit positions, so if you want a 32-bit result it's always safe to truncate your inputs instead of doing a 64-bit subtract and truncating the result.  Same for left shift, or the low `N` bits of an `N x N` multiply.  See also [Which 2's complement integer operations can be used without zeroing high bits in the inputs, if only the low part of the result is wanted?](//stackoverflow.com/q/34377711)

Comment: I knew that, but I didn't know that the Arduino's method would manage to handle the rollover in NTP, not quite accidentally, but without needing to detect it per se. I figured that, since the time is an absolute delta past a certain start date, that any rollover would HAVE to give the wrong time once it occurred.